# Copy data between tables using create table with select

Tags: mysql

I have aitisi (id, name1, surname1, father1, birthdate1, name2, surname2, father2, birthdate2... to 5, cost, begins, expires, plan, address, phone, city, zip) and I want to copy the surnameX, nameX, fatherX, birthdateX (X= 1 to 5) columns to a new table members (id, tid, name, surname, father, birthdate) where tid is a lookup key to table1.id

I tried with MySQL but didn't get it right so I finally did id with PHP:

```
$query_aitisi = "SELECT * FROM aitisi order by id asc";
$aitisi = mysql_query($query_aitisi, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_aitisi = mysql_fetch_assoc($aitisi);
$totalRows_aitisi = mysql_num_rows($aitisi);

do {
  for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    if ($row_aitisi['on_te'.$i]<>'') { 
    $query_copy = "insert into members (symbid, name, surname, father, birthdate) 
    values ('".$row_aitisi[id]."','".$row_aitisi['surname'.$i]."','".$row_aitisi['name'.$i]."','".$row_aitisi['father'.$i]."','".$row_aitisi['birthdate'.$i]."')";
$copy = mysql_query($query_copy, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
    }
  }
} while ($row_aitisi = mysql_fetch_assoc($aitisi));
```

However, I'd really like to know the proper use of a "create table as select" statement for future use. Anybody? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following query should work just fine

```
create table members (symbid, surname, name, father, birthdate)
    (select id, surname1, name1, father1, birthdate1 from aitisi where on_te1 != ''
    union all
    select id, surname2, name2, father2, birthdate2 from aitisi where on_te2 != ''
    union all
    select id, surname3, name3, father3, birthdate3 from aitisi where on_te3 != ''
    union all
    select id, surname4, name4, father4, birthdate4 from aitisi where on_te4 != ''
    union all
    select id, surname5, name5, father5, birthdate5 from aitisi where on_te5 != '')
```

Comment: That simply copies the entire table to a new one. Not what I'm looking for I'm afraid.

Comment: I got Your question completly wrong :) I have updated my answer.

Comment: Havent had much time to modify it exactly to my needs but the first attempt gave me an error. I'll look into it more carefully and keep you updated.